# Upgrading Scipy on IronPython

Tags: scipy, ironpython

I'm kind of new to Scipy and IronPython, so please excuse any dummy question I might be asking.

Anyway, I'm trying to upgrade my scipy version to >1.1 on my IronPython 2.7.5 (OS is Windows 7 64bit) but I am not really sure how to do it.

My current scipy version is 1.0.0.

I've tried to run from command prompt:

```
ipy -X:Frames -m pip install --upgrade scipy
```

But I'm getting this:

```
Downloading/unpacking scipy
C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py:1: DeprecationWarning: object.__new__() takes no para
meters
  # urllib3/connectionpool.py
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement scipy
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for scipy
```

Any help on how to get it to work will be appreciated. Alternatively, if there are other ways to easily install newer compiled version of scipy on IronPython env, it's also OK - I just need to know.